# How to set up power line frequency filtration in openCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I use python and opencv to build  a stereo tracker using two cameras.

The question is how to set up power line frequency filtration in openCV version 3.0.0 (or any orher). I know that the camera I use (microsoftHD3000) has this property and it can be set from v4l2 in linux and on windows I can use skype to set it once, but this is ugly.

Unfortunately I can not find the corresponding property in CAP_PROP_* constants.

What is the proper way to do it if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the power line frequency setting as well as anything else using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37057262/3330141), assuming you have installed GStreamer support (`flag: -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON`).

If you don't have GStreamer, you can use v4l utils directly from terminal.
Since it is a prerequisite for installing OpenCV, so you should already have it.

Run:

for 50Hz:

```
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl power_line_frequency=1
```

for 60Hz:

```
v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl power_line_frequency=2
```

to check current setting:

```
 v4l2-ctl --all
```

**Reference**: [Webcam flicker due to electricity grid frequency rate - Fedora Forums](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-299789.html)

Comment: @TalhaIrfan I will, can you please specify?

Comment: @sleepyhead Hey, thanks, so having it compiled with GStreamer support is the answer. Regarding edits: I think everything beyond the first paragraph is not essential (i.e. it answers a different question from what was asked), so it's better to have it removed for clarity. Otherwise I accept.