# How can I change webcam properties that OpenCV doesn't support but v4l2 API does?

Tags: python, opencv, subprocess, v4l2, ubuntu-15.04

I'm using **OpenCV 3.1** and **Python 2.7** to capture video frames from my webcam, **Logitech C270**. I'm also using **video4linux2(v4l2)** to set the properties of my camera but this led to a few problems. My OS is **Ubuntu 15.04**.

The specific property I'm trying to change is **absolute_exposure**.

I'm able to change it manually using **v4l2** API via terminal, with the command `v4l2-ctl --set-ctrl exposure_absolute=40`, and it works nice but I need to write a script for this task.

Using OpenCV's `set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, 20)` leads to "VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: Property Exposure(15) not supported by device". I'm sure the webcam supports the change of this property since it's possible to do so using v4l2, then I assume the problem is with OpenCV's wrapper.

I also tried to use **subprocess** lib to send a terminal command and change the property using **v4l2**. The command is `subprocess.call('v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --set-ctrl exposure_absolute=20', shell=True)`.

The result is that exposure_absolute changes but it isn't applied to my current video capture. Image 1 shows the result after setting the property via script. Image 2 shows the result after setting the same property via terminal, with the same video capture active.

[Setting exposure_absolute via script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G94J6.png) (image 1)

[Setting exposure_absolute via terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0uMY.png) (image 2)

Image 2 was taken right after image 1, the highlighted line is the same of image 1.

Am I doing something wrong on the subprocess call? Or how can I make the change of this property using a script?

Also, why `cv2.VideoCapture(id)` resets the camera properties, it's no use changing them before running the script, and is it possible to stop that?

**__________________________________________________**

**Edit:** I maybe found a workaround for this problem. The subprocess call is indeed right, I just had to use `cv2.read()` once before changing the properties, apparently the first `cv2.read()` is where the camera properties are reset. I still don't know how to stop it from automatically resetting webcam's properties though.

Comment: Looking at the source code in `modules\highgui\src\cap_libv4l.cpp` (specifically at the `icvSetControl` function), it would appear that you should be able to pass in a V4L control code instead of the CV2 codes. So, find the numerical value of `V4L2_CID_EXPOSURE_ABSOLUTE` ([maybe 0x902](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/uapi/linux/v4l2-controls.h#L88)?) and call the `set` function with that -- `set(0x902, 20)`.

Answer (score 5):

If you build opencv with GStreamer support (flag: -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON)  you can open a VideoCapture using a GStreamer pipeline where you can specify all kind of parameters for v4l2:

```
std::string cameraPipeline;
cameraPipeline ="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 extra-controls=\"c,exposure_auto=1,exposure_absolute=500\" ! ";
cameraPipeline+="video/x-raw, format=BGR, framerate=30/1, width=(int)1280,height=(int)720 ! ";
cameraPipeline+="appsink";

VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(cameraPipeline);
```

This is works in C++ and Python. You can get the full list of controls by typing this in a terminal :
     v4l2-ctl --list-ctrls-menus